# Activating Slickquiz.js on a cms-page

Tags: jquery

Under: http://polesto.com/pole-quiz#
I'm trying to get jQuery plugin to excecute, but currently I'm facing a dead-end. The jquery is run under noConflict mode, but the excecution is not running under these or many other trial runs.

Anyone care to enlighten me, as js with magento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error `SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`.
The code that generates this error is

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( $(function () {
$('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz({
    // options
        }); 
    });
});
```

Looks to me that there are a lot of `jQuery` calls in there.
not sure, but most probably the code should look like this:

```
    jQuery( function ($) {
       $('#slickQuiz').slickQuiz(); 
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was even simpler, the html-tags within the page had been edited to noncompliant form, by the wysiwyg-editor.